# OpenCV iPhone camera, changing CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_ * has no effect

Tags: iphone, cocoa, opencv, camera

i was playing with OpenCV2 + iPhone camera capture

```
self.capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY);
...   
IplImage * frame = cvQueryFrame(self.capture);
```

_

```
NSLog(@"CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_WHITEBALANCE = %f", cvGetCaptureProperty(self.capture ,CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_WHITEBALANCE));
NSLog(@"CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_TORCH = %f", cvGetCaptureProperty(self.capture ,CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_TORCH));
NSLog(@"CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_FOCUS = %f", cvGetCaptureProperty(self.capture ,CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_FOCUS));
NSLog(@"CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_FLASH = %f", cvGetCaptureProperty(self.capture ,CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_FLASH));
NSLog(@"CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_EXPOSURE = %f", cvGetCaptureProperty(self.capture, CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_EXPOSURE));
```

however, changing any of the CV_CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_* has no effect, i found out that most of them can be change to 0,1,2 (after querying back the values with cvGetCaptureProperty())

but it has no effect :(

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS OpenCV port is still [in development](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/2012#2012-06-26) - just be patient and wait a few months for better support.

Or, better, just take the sources, read them, implement the features and push them back as a patch. You'll gain glory, thank-you's and valuable open-source development experience.